# How to wait for retrofit response in rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I use retrofit2 with rxjava extension.

I have a list of REST API urls and want to do this:

- for each

  - check whether a corresponding file locally exists
  - if yes: call the API and store the response or the HTTP error
  - if not: store a customized error
- return the list of those results

My problem is: `apply` returns (with an empty `RequestResult`) before the server response is received. I think, I understand why, but I don't know how to fix it, because I need to return a `RequestResult` and not the Retrofit observable.

How can this be solved?

Here is my code:

```
@GET
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> enroll(@Url String url);


class RequestResult {
    CustomException error;
    Response<ResponseBody> response;
}

Observable<ClassOfListItem> observable = Observable.fromIterable(listOfItems);

observable
    .flatMap(new Function<ClassOfListItem, ObservableSource<RequestResult>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableSource<RequestResult> apply(ClassOfListItem listItem) throws Exception {

            RequestResult requestResult = new RequestResult();
            if (fileExists(listItem.url))   {
                Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> callObservable = restAPI.enroll(listItem.url)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

                callObservable
                    .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                            onPremiseEnrollmentResult.response = responseBodyResponse;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            onPremiseEnrollmentResult.error = new CustomException(e);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                        }
                    });
            }
            else {
                requestResult.error = new CustomException("file not found");
            }
            return Observable.just(requestResult);
        }
    }
    .toList()
    .observerOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<RequestResult>>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("onError", e.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<RequestResult> requestResults) {
            // parse results
        }
    }
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flatMap()` operator allows you to turn one observable into a different observable. You have a nested observer chain inside your `apply()` which is not part of the observer chain, so it will be empty because it has not completed yet.

To fix this, when the file exists, return the observable.

```
observable
  .flatMap(new Function<ClassOfListItem, ObservableSource<RequestResult>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<RequestResult> apply(ClassOfListItem listItem) throws Exception {
        RequestResult requestResult = new RequestResult();
        if (fileExists(listItem.url))   {
            return restAPI.enroll(listItem.url)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        }
        return Observable.error( new CustomException("file not found") );
    }
}
.toList()
.observerOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
.subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<RequestResult>>() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

        Log.d("onError", e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<RequestResult> requestResults) {
        // parse results
    }
}
```

If you need to capture both errors and successes into the list, then you can add `map()` operator to wrap `RequestResult` around the response and `onErrorResumeNext()` to wrap `RequestResult` around the error before the `toList()` operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making api call on background thread then what you can do is invoke it synchronously....in your case your retrofit api method would change to following

```
Call<Response<ResponseBody>> enroll(@Url String url);
```

and you'd invoke by calling `restAPI.enroll(listItem.url).execute()`